# Can I use regex conditions without them being part of the result?

Tags: regex

I've got some file path strings like that:

```
\\server01\folder\some subfolder\THIS\page1.pdf
```

How can I get `THIS` string with a regex while checking that the end of the string is `.pdf`?

I tried `\\\S*\.pdf$` to get `\THIS\page1.pdf`which I now could use to split by `\` to get the value, but I wondered if there is a regex which will give me `THIS` direcly.

For clearance: I don't know what string `THIS`would be, it's just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group

```
\\\\.*\\([^\s\\]+)\\\w+\.pdf$
```

**Explanation**

- `\\\\` Match `\\`
- `.*\\` Match until the last `\`
- `([^\s\\]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars except `\`
- `\\\w+` Match `\` and 1+ word chars
- `\.pdf` Match `.pdf`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0yMhIC/1)

If the filename can contain dots and other character as well:

```
\\\\.*\\([^\s\\]+)\\[^\\\r\n]+\.pdf$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A78liW/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want capturing groups:

```
[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+\.pdf$)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSCmu3/1)